# Use std::future and std::async in Android (NDK)

Tags: c++, c++11, android-ndk, clang, libstdc++

I have many other C++11 features working, but when I write:

```
std::future<void> test;
```

Compiler says:

```
MyFile.h:43:23: error: field 'test' has incomplete type
     std::future<void> test;
                       ^
```

It also fails with any other type in the template parameter.

I'm trying to compile this on Mac OS X (v10.8.4), with NDK r9 and gnu libstdc++ 4.9.
In my Application.mk i have this:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.8
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -std=gnu++11
```

I've also tried changing to NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang with no luck; error changes to:

```
implicit instantiation of undefined template
```

And in my Android.mk I've added this:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=gnu++11
```

Is there any way that I could use std::async and std::future with NDK?